# While creating a react app I'm getting following error or errors

Tags: reactjs, npm

I ran create-react-app and get this error message I did the followings like uninstalling global and so no but getting the same again and again.

```
You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.0, which is behind the latest release (4.0.1).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.       

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:   
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path J:\Akhlak_hossain_jim
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c ""create-react-app" "ahj-app" "--use-npm""

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Akhlak Hossain Jim\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-24T15_16_27_423Z-debug.log
```

---

**Edit:**

I've also tried the following:

1. [Using npx instead.](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app) - but that's not working and is showing the above error message.
2. Uninstalled create-react-app using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` before running `npx create-react-app ahj-app`  - however that also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Above worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use npm to install "create-react-app" instead use npx this way:

`npx create-react-app my-app`

it will always use the lastest version

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the following command.

npm uninstall -g create-react-app

then again install

npm install -g create-react-app

PS D:\ReactProjects> npx create-react-app sample-app

Creating a new React app in D:\ReactProjects\sample-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

Answer (score 0):

```
npx create-react-app@5.0.0 ahj-app
```

Specify the latest version explicitly when creating new app